# Unable to add tracking #

Tags: magento2, php, database, code, web

Is there anyone available for the help please. I was trying to add tracking # into the order but I'm giving an error.

Complete process is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18XS213g0otdMZoJPDxQe5s_r9nOg2wv3/view?usp=sharing

Erros Message:

TypeError: Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\PathValidator::validate(): Argument #1 ($directoryPath) must be of type string, null given, called in /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filesystem/Directory/Read.php on line 80 and defined in /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filesystem/Directory/PathValidator.php:38
Stack trace:
#0 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filesystem/Directory/Read.php(80): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\PathValidator->validate()
#1 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filesystem/Directory/Read.php(277): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read->validatePath()
#2 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/app/code/MageWorx/OptionBase/Helper/Data.php(327): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read->readFile()
#3 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/generated/code/MageWorx/OptionBase/Helper/Data/Interceptor.php(77): MageWorx\OptionBase\Helper\Data->getModuleVersion()
#4 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/app/code/MageWorx/OptionBase/Helper/Data.php(356): MageWorx\OptionBase\Helper\Data\Interceptor->getModuleVersion()
#5 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/generated/code/MageWorx/OptionBase/Helper/Data/Interceptor.php(86): MageWorx\OptionBase\Helper\Data->checkModuleVersion()
#6 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/app/code/MageWorx/OptionFeatures/Model/QtyMultiplier.php(140): MageWorx\OptionBase\Helper\Data\Interceptor->checkModuleVersion()
#7 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/app/code/MageWorx/OptionFeatures/Observer/SubtractQtyMultiplierQty.php(94): MageWorx\OptionFeatures\Model\QtyMultiplier->getQtyMultiplierQtyForCurrentItemQty()
#8 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(88): MageWorx\OptionFeatures\Observer\SubtractQtyMultiplierQty->execute()
#9 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(74): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod()
#10 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager.php(65): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch()
#11 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch()
#12 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(832): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch()
#13 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->afterSave()
#14 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\Interceptor->___callParent()
#15 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}()
#16 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Shipment/Interceptor.php(815): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#17 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/VersionControl/AbstractDb.php(56): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\Interceptor->afterSave()
#18 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/AbstractDb.php(402): Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\VersionControl\AbstractDb->processAfterSaves()
#19 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(658): Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb->save()
#20 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Shipment/Interceptor.php(752): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->save()
#21 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DB/Transaction.php(134): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\Interceptor->save()
#22 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/app/code/Magento/Shipping/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Shipment/Save.php(95): Magento\Framework\DB\Transaction->save()
#23 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/app/code/Magento/Shipping/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Shipment/Save.php(168): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save->_saveShipment()
#24 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save->execute()
#25 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor->___callParent()
#26 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}()
#27 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Shipping/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Shipment/Save/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#28 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Action/Action.php(111): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor->execute()
#29 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/app/code/Magento/Backend/App/AbstractAction.php(151): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch()
#30 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch()
#31 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor->___callParent()
#32 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/app/code/Magento/Backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(145): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}()
#33 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch()
#34 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}()
#35 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Shipping/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Shipment/Save/Interceptor.php(32): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#36 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php(245): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor->dispatch()
#37 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php(212): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->getActionResponse()
#38 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php(147): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest()
#39 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch()
#40 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent()
#41 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}()
#42 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#43 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch()
#44 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#45 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#46 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/pub/index.php(33): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run()
#47 {main}
**Fatal error**:  Uncaught Exception: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed in /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Session/SessionManager.php:133
Stack trace:
#0 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Session/SessionManager.php(133): session_write_close()
#1 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth/Session/Interceptor.php(104): Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->writeClose()
#2 [internal function]: Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session\Interceptor->writeClose()
#3 {main}
thrown in **/home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Session/SessionManager.php** on line **133**

**Fatal error**:  Uncaught Exception: User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back in /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 4067 in /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:62
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler()
#1 /home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(4067): trigger_error()
#2 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->__destruct()
#3 {main}
thrown in **/home/ab9fc241/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/ErrorHandler.php** on line **62**

Comment: Is there anyone available please?